# How would I output the data I'm trying to find after I send the request

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$.get('http://www.roblox.com/',function(dataz){

    $(dataz).find('.member-name-container a').each(function() {
        var ga = $( this ).attr('title')
        console.log( $( this ).attr('title') )
    })
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://rproxy.tk/rapi/GetIdByUsername/" +  ga,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to get it to output the text it finds from the `(dataz).find` part and make it send a request the the `url: "http://rproxy.tk/rapi/GetIdByUsername/" +  ga` and output the pages text (the users id)

Thank you.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Are you trying to put the page contents into `dataz` or into another element?

Comment: I'm trying to console.log the page contents, not into dataz

Comment: Your code appears to be fine. You can achieve that in the success callback of the ajax call.

Comment: What's the problem that you are facing while doing the console.log? Isn't it writing the correct data to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly.

```
$.get('http://www.roblox.com/', function (dataz) {

    $(dataz).find('.member-name-container a').each(function () {

        var ga = $(this).attr('title');
        console.log(ga);

        $.get('http://rproxy.tk/rapi/GetIdByUsername/' + ga, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```